# MySQL connect parameters won't work when stored in another file (sometimes)

Tags: php, mysql

This has been baffling me for a few hours now and I'm reaching the point of giving up.

My project has 3 relevant files:

```
dbconfig.php
register.php
testmysql.php
```

dbconfig.php has this function:

```
        public function connString()
        {
            $connString['host'] = $this->host;
            $connString['username'] = $this->username;
            $connString['password'] = $this->password;
            $connString['database'] = $this->database;                      
            return $connString;
        }
```

I do this in `testmysql.php` and it works perfectly:

```
    require('dbconfig.php');
    $dbObject = new dbconfig();

    $conn = $dbObject->connString();
    mysql_connect($conn['host'],$conn['username'],$conn['password']) or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($conn['database']) or die(mysql_error());
```

But when I do the same thing in `register.php`, it fails:

```
<div class="div_texbox">
    <select id="field1" name="field1" class="textbox">                                              
        <option value="0">Select</option>
        <?php                                           
            require('dbconfig.php');
            $dbObject = new dbconfig();

            $conn = $dbObject->connString();
            mysql_connect($conn['host'],$conn['username'],$conn['password']) or die(mysql_error());
            mysql_select_db($conn['database']) or die(mysql_error());

            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table") or die ('error selecting');                                            

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ))
            {
                echo "<option value=\"" . $row['ID'] . "\">" . $row['value'] . "</option>";
            }                                                       
        ?>                                          
    </select>
</div>
```

Details on when I say 'it fails':
`Field1` is a select box that is supposed to populate, but it doesn't and no further fields in the form show up (presumably because of the `die`).
I tried installing a PHP debugger to see the message being thrown but could not get one working.
If I hardcode in the connect parameters, it all works.
A `var_dump` of `$conn` shows it to be holding all the right values at all the right indices (also evident in the fact that `testmysql.php` works).

Also, it some troubleshooting made it seem that it is failing at `mysql_connect`

I analyzed my HTML code of the rendered page to see the output of the PHP script and this is what it shows:

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class dbconfig in C:\wamp\www\site\dbconfig.php on line 10
Call Stack
#TimeMemoryFunctionLocation
10.0005698544{main}(  )..\register.php:0
21.2728763824require( 'C:\wamp\www\site\dbconfig.php' )..\register.php:106
```

dbconfig constructor

```
public function __construct($config = NULL)
        {
            if ($config != NULL)
            {
                $this->host = $config['hostname'];
                $this->database = $config['database'];
                $this->username = $config['username'];
                $this->password = $config['password'];
            }
            else
            {
                $this->host = $this->defaultConfig['hostname'];
                $this->database =$this->defaultConfig['database'];
                $this->username = $this->defaultConfig['username'];
                $this->password = $this->defaultConfig['password'];

            }
        }
```

Comment: um... does `SELECT * FROM table` give you a table with an `ID` and `value` column?

Comment: [`or die()` must die](http://www.phpfreaks.com/blog/or-die-must-die)

Comment: Yes, there are records in `table`, and the `table` table has columns with different names. I only changed it when posting to SO. Like I said, simply hardcoding the `mysql_connect`parameters makes it work like a charm.

Comment: @xbonez Enable error reporting. Place this above your `require` line; `ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: Added the line and ran the page again. I still don't see any errors, yet the Select field doesn't populate. Ok, I was able to get the error and have edited my question to reflect that. The error clears something, so I'm trying to see if I can fix it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're including `dbconfig.php` more than once which is causing the *cannot redeclare class* fatal error.

Change any reference of

```
require('dbconfig.php')
```

to

```
require_once 'dbconfig.php';
```

While you're at it, [stop using `or die()`](http://www.phpfreaks.com/blog/or-die-must-die) and switch to [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [parameterised statements](http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/forum-replies.cfm?t=1234522).

Comment: changed `require` to `require_once` but same problem. Could the problem be caused in `$dbObject = new dbconfig();`. How can I have it so that if an instance of `dbconfig()` has already been declared, the same instance gets returned?

Comment: Also, thanks for the tip about `die()` and `PDO`. I'll stop using `die` right away and look into `PDO` as well

Comment: `Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class dbconfig in C:\wamp\www\tutor\dbconfig.php`. Posting my dbconfig constructor in the question

Comment: @xbonez In that case, you're either defining the `dbconfig` class in more than one location or you haven't changed **all** your `require` calls to `require_once`

Comment: @xbonez To answer the question in your first comment; as much as I'm not a fan of it, look up the [Singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)

Comment: yes, you were correct. There was one `require` I was missing. Thanks!